# Sharing Apps with Bluetooth or WiFi

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

Is sharing an app between devices using Bluetooth or WiFi considered an install of this app and will be counted in current installs or it should only be downloaded from Google Play directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Only the installs from Google Play will count

You can test it by publishing your app in closed beta (so no one else will be able to see/download it) and installing from Google Play / any other source you would like to try